# SQL Server 2017 Doesn't Validate User Function when updating Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is a crazy one, seems like a bug to me.  I changed the signature of a scalar user function to include an additional parameter, and I was trying to refactor my sprocs which call it, and I noticed an issue which I was able to recreate with two test functions.

First, I created a scalar user function called "test_function" which take a single integer parameter. It doesn't matter what the function does for this test.

Then I created a sproc, which has a simple temp table of 1 column value "thevalue"

Then I execute the alter or create update, but ***without*** the parameter:

[image: intellisense error]

Intellisense correctly indicates that there's a parameter missing in test_function. But here's where the problem occurs, I can still create or alter this sproc without any errors!

However, if I remove the temp table from the equation, and update a variable, I get the expect error when trying to create or alter the sproc:

[image: intellisense error]

Is there a possible setting or a way to flag this specific sproc so that the error would occur and the sproc not be altered?

Comment: You have more than enough reputation to know why images of code and error messages aren't helpful.

Comment: This is deferred compilation, and unfortunately considered a feature, not a bug. Any statement involving a temporary table will be put on the backburner to be evaluated for correctness only when it's actually executed, even if it contains code that could obviously never execute correctly regardless of how the temp table looks.

Comment: @JeroenMostert why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, I had no idea it would defer everything in the statement. Will look to create table variables to see if it avoids that issue.

Comment: I converted to a table variable and the error is caught properly. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that table variables have their own, well documented problems with cardinality estimates (where the optimizer may choose to assume that there's always only one row in the table, or at best a handful). They are also more limited in what indexing is possible. Replacing temp tables with variables to get better compilation feedback may be tempting, but don't do it mindlessly without keeping an eye on possible performance regressions.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852

Comment: Guys, it's impossible to show tool tip errors without a picture.

Comment: Why don't you respond here? https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/piracy-file-sharing-why-arent-songs-movies-or-books-given-for-free